# I can't figure out why the page is jumping to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<h1><i class="fa fa-check"></i>CSS & jQuery To Do Checklist</h1>
<form id="todo-list">
  <span class="todo-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" checked/>
    <label for="1" class="todo">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      Have a good idea
    </label>
    <span class="delete-item" title="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="todo-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2"/>
    <label for="2" class="todo">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      Plan idea execution
    </label>
    <span class="delete-item" title="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="todo-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="3"/>
    <label for="3" class="todo">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      Execute idea
    </label>
    <span class="delete-item" title="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
    <span class="todo-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="4"/>
    <label for="4" class="todo">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      Celebrate with a cold one
    </label>
    <span class="delete-item" title="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
  <div id="add-todo">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    Add an Item
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
*{
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
        transition:.25s ease-in-out;
font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
line-height:18px;
box-sizing:border-box;
margin:0;
}
body{
background:#f8f8f8;
}
h1{
text-align:center;
padding:50px 0;
font-size:30px;
margin:0;
font-weight:200;
color:#454545;
}
h1 .fa-check{
font-size:30px;
margin-right:10px;
color:#0eb0b7;
}
#todo-list{
width:500px;
margin:0 auto 50px auto;
padding:50px;
background:white;
position:relative;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
/*border-radius*/
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
}
#todo-list:before{
content:"";
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
top:50%;
bottom:0;
left:10px;
right:10px;
/*border-radius*/
-webkit-border-radius:100px / 10px;
   -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
        border-radius:100px / 10px;
}
.todo-wrap{
display:block;
position:relative;
padding-left:35px;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 0 -1px #ebebeb;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 0 -1px #ebebeb;
        box-shadow:0 2px 0 -1px #ebebeb;
}
.todo-wrap:last-of-type{
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:none;
   -moz-box-shadow:none;
        box-shadow:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
position:absolute;
height:0;
width:0;
opacity:0;
top:-600px;
}
.todo{
display:inline-block;
font-weight:200;
padding:10px 5px;
height:37px;
position:relative;
}
.todo:before{
content:'';
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:calc(50% + 2px);
left:0;
width:0%;
height:1px;
background:#cd4400;
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
        transition:.25s ease-in-out;
}
.todo:after{
content:'';
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
height:18px;
width:18px;
top:9px;
left:-25px;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #d8d8d8;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #d8d8d8;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #d8d8d8;
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
        transition:.25s ease-in-out;
/*border-radius*/
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
   -moz-border-radius:4px;
        border-radius:4px;
}
.todo:hover:after{
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #949494;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #949494;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #949494;
}
.todo .fa-check{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
left:-31px;
top:0;
font-size:1px;
line-height:36px;
width:36px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
color:transparent;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white, -1px -1px 0 white;
}
:checked + .todo{
color:#717171;
}
:checked + .todo:before{
width:100%;
}
:checked + .todo:after{
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #0eb0b7;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #0eb0b7;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #0eb0b7;
}
:checked + .todo .fa-check{
font-size:20px;
line-height:35px;
color:#0eb0b7;
}
/* Delete Items */

.delete-item{
display:block;
position:absolute;
height:36px;
width:36px;
line-height:36px;
right:0;
top:0;
text-align:center;
color:#d8d8d8;
opacity:0;
}
.todo-wrap:hover .delete-item{
opacity:1;
}
.delete-item:hover{
color:#cd4400;
}
/* Add Items */

#add-todo{
padding:25px 0 0 0;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:200;
color:#d8d8d8;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
}
#add-todo:hover{
color:#6bc569;
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:none;
   -moz-transition:none;
     -o-transition:none;
        transition:none;
}
#add-todo .fa-plus{
font-size:14px;
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:none;
   -moz-transition:none;
     -o-transition:none;
        transition:none;
}
.input-todo{
border:none;
outline:none;
font-weight:200;
position:relative;
top:-1px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}
.editing{
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.editing.todo-wrap {
  box-shadow:0 0 400px rgba(0,0,0,.8),inset 0 0px 0 2px #ebebeb;
}
```

JS:

```
// add items
$('#add-todo').click(function(){
  var lastSibling = $('#todo-list > .todo-wrap:last-of-type > input').attr('id');
  var newId = Number(lastSibling) + 1;

  $(this).before('<span class="editing todo-wrap"><input type="checkbox" id="'+newId+'"/><label for="'+newId+'" class="todo"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><input type="text" class="input-todo" id="input-todo'+newId+'"/></label></div>');
  $('#input-todo'+newId+'').parent().parent().animate({
    height:"36px"
  },200)
  $('#input-todo'+newId+'').focus();

    $('#input-todo'+newId+'').enterKey(function(){
    $(this).trigger('enterEvent');
  })

  $('#input-todo'+newId+'').on('blur enterEvent',function(){
    var todoTitle = $('#input-todo'+newId+'').val();
    var todoTitleLength = todoTitle.length;
    if (todoTitleLength > 0) {
      $(this).before(todoTitle);
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('editing');
      $(this).parent().after('<span class="delete-item" title="remove"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>');
      $(this).remove();
      $('.delete-item').click(function(){
        var parentItem = $(this).parent();
        parentItem.animate({
          left:"-30%",
          height:0,
          opacity:0
        },200);
        setTimeout(function(){ $(parentItem).remove(); }, 1000);
      });
    }
    else {
      $('.editing').animate({
        height:'0px'
      },200);
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.editing').remove()
      },400)
    }
  })

});

// remove items 

$('.delete-item').click(function(){
  var parentItem = $(this).parent();
  parentItem.animate({
    left:"-30%",
    height:0,
    opacity:0
  },200);
  setTimeout(function(){ $(parentItem).remove(); }, 1000);
});

// Enter Key detect

$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                fnc.call(this, ev);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

or, a sample of the working the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/veXRrr

I thought it would've been because of the `.click()` and so I tried to do `e.preventDefault();` but nope.

I even tried to make the elements in the html links instead of just the labels and add `onclick="return false;"` but also no.

I'm honestly at a loss since I thought the jump only happened with click or link elements so not sure where else to look.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: it would have been nice of you to post the code directly here...

Comment: @Salketer seems like I can never get it right :D I'll update

Comment: Thx, wasn't trying to be picky, but codepen still ain't open on my damn slow internet! Next time, try the code snippet tool, at the right of the image when editing... You'll see, you get a full codepen directly on stack overflow :)

Comment: @Salketer got it! Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preventDefault()` is when you want to prevent the default action of an element. You would use that if you were clicking on `anchor` tags for the functionality or something similar(which is not the case here). The reason this issue is happening is because when you click on the `label`, it is trying to focus the `input` which is higher up on the page. You can fix this by just setting `display:none;` on the inputs:

```js
// add items
$('#add-todo').click(function(){
  var lastSibling = $('#todo-list > .todo-wrap:last-of-type > input').attr('id');
  var newId = Number(lastSibling) + 1;
      
  $(this).before('<span class="editing todo-wrap"><input type="checkbox" id="'+newId+'"/><label for="'+newId+'" class="todo"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><input type="text" class="input-todo" id="input-todo'+newId+'"/></label></div>');
  $('#input-todo'+newId+'').parent().parent().animate({
    height:"36px"
  },200)
  $('#input-todo'+newId+'').focus();
  
 $('#input-todo'+newId+'').enterKey(function(){
    $(this).trigger('enterEvent');
  })
  
  $('#input-todo'+newId+'').on('blur enterEvent',function(){
    var todoTitle = $('#input-todo'+newId+'').val();
    var todoTitleLength = todoTitle.length;
    if (todoTitleLength > 0) {
      $(this).before(todoTitle);
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('editing');
      $(this).parent().after('<span class="delete-item" title="remove"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span>');
      $(this).remove();
      $('.delete-item').click(function(){
        var parentItem = $(this).parent();
        parentItem.animate({
          left:"-30%",
          height:0,
          opacity:0
        },200);
        setTimeout(function(){ $(parentItem).remove(); }, 1000);
      });
    }
    else {
      $('.editing').animate({
        height:'0px'
      },200);
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.editing').remove()
      },400)
    }
  })

});

// remove items 

$('.delete-item').click(function(){
  var parentItem = $(this).parent();
  parentItem.animate({
    left:"-30%",
    height:0,
    opacity:0
  },200);
  setTimeout(function(){ $(parentItem).remove(); }, 1000);
});

// Enter Key detect

$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                fnc.call(this, ev);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

```css
*{
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
        transition:.25s ease-in-out;
font-family:helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
line-height:18px;
box-sizing:border-box;
margin:0;
}
body{
background:#f8f8f8;
}
h1{
text-align:center;
padding:50px 0;
font-size:30px;
margin:0;
font-weight:200;
color:#454545;
}
h1 .fa-check{
font-size:30px;
margin-right:10px;
color:#0eb0b7;
}
#todo-list{
width:500px;
margin:0 auto 50px auto;
padding:50px;
background:white;
position:relative;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
/*border-radius*/
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
}
#todo-list:before{
content:"";
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
top:50%;
bottom:0;
left:10px;
right:10px;
/*border-radius*/
-webkit-border-radius:100px / 10px;
   -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
        border-radius:100px / 10px;
}
.todo-wrap{
display:block;
position:relative;
padding-left:35px;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 0 -1px #ebebeb;
   -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 0 -1px #ebebeb;
        box-shadow:0 2px 0 -1px #ebebeb;
}
.todo-wrap:last-of-type{
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:none;
   -moz-box-shadow:none;
        box-shadow:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
position:absolute;
height:0;
width:0;
opacity:0;
top:-600px;
}
.todo{
display:inline-block;
font-weight:200;
padding:10px 5px;
height:37px;
position:relative;
}
.todo:before{
content:'';
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:calc(50% + 2px);
left:0;
width:0%;
height:1px;
background:#cd4400;
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
        transition:.25s ease-in-out;
}
.todo:after{
content:'';
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
height:18px;
width:18px;
top:9px;
left:-25px;
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #d8d8d8;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #d8d8d8;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #d8d8d8;
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition:.25s ease-in-out;
        transition:.25s ease-in-out;
/*border-radius*/
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
   -moz-border-radius:4px;
        border-radius:4px;
}
.todo:hover:after{
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #949494;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #949494;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #949494;
}
.todo .fa-check{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
left:-31px;
top:0;
font-size:1px;
line-height:36px;
width:36px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
color:transparent;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 white, -1px -1px 0 white;
}
:checked + .todo{
color:#717171;
}
:checked + .todo:before{
width:100%;
}
:checked + .todo:after{
/*box-shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #0eb0b7;
   -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #0eb0b7;
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px #0eb0b7;
}
:checked + .todo .fa-check{
font-size:20px;
line-height:35px;
color:#0eb0b7;
}
/* Delete Items */

.delete-item{
display:block;
position:absolute;
height:36px;
width:36px;
line-height:36px;
right:0;
top:0;
text-align:center;
color:#d8d8d8;
opacity:0;
}
.todo-wrap:hover .delete-item{
opacity:1;
}
.delete-item:hover{
color:#cd4400;
}
/* Add Items */

#add-todo{
padding:25px 0 0 0;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:200;
color:#d8d8d8;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
}
#add-todo:hover{
color:#6bc569;
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:none;
   -moz-transition:none;
     -o-transition:none;
        transition:none;
}
#add-todo .fa-plus{
font-size:14px;
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:none;
   -moz-transition:none;
     -o-transition:none;
        transition:none;
}
.input-todo{
border:none;
outline:none;
font-weight:200;
position:relative;
top:-1px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}
.editing{
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.editing.todo-wrap {
  box-shadow:0 0 400px rgba(0,0,0,.8),inset 0 0px 0 2px #ebebeb;
}

/* FIX PAGE JUMPING */
.todo-wrap input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1><i class="fa fa-check"></i>CSS & jQuery To Do Checklist</h1>
<form id="todo-list">
  <span class="todo-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" checked/>
    <label for="1" class="todo">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;">Have a good idea</a>
    </label>
    <span class="delete-item" title="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="todo-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="2"/>
    <label for="2" class="todo">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      Plan idea execution
    </label>
    <span class="delete-item" title="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="todo-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="3"/>
    <label for="3" class="todo">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      Execute idea
    </label>
    <span class="delete-item" title="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
 <span class="todo-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" id="4"/>
    <label for="4" class="todo">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
      Celebrate with a cold one
    </label>
    <span class="delete-item" title="remove">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
  <div id="add-todo">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    Add an Item
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize this. Thank you so much!